# Making an elastic waistband on clothing?

Tags: modeling

I made these pants with this tutorial another user directed me: http://www.blendernation.com/2016/02/25/cloth-sewing-in-blender/

I followed the tutorial and got it to this:

[image]

I want to add an elastic waistband around the pant's waists and ankles so that the pants don't droop like that. How can I do this?

Comment: Try to use cloth pinning. See how it works here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4cZAJ5aKwGo.

Comment: I dont want to pin the clothes though because I want it to travel with the character if he moves :/

Comment: Don't worry. Pinning obeys armature. Please see the example of my animation here: http://giphy.com/gifs/animation-3d-blender-xThuWdpRX2YsVDzfHy I've pinned the top of the cape, and as you can see all works fine. Just pin the vertices around the belt and ankles areas.

Comment: Im having difficulties hooking the vertex group of the top ring of the pants to the character. How do I pin these? :/ The tutorial doesnt go in detail to this.

Comment: Relatated previous post: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/49180/2843

Answer (score 5):

You may achieve the effect you want using a ***cloth pinning***.
[image]

In *Edit Mode* select the vertices around the belt and ankles areas. Create a new *vertex group* and call it ***'pin'***. Assign vertices to that group.
[image]

In the *Cloth* settings check the ***Pinning*** checkbox and input the ***'pin'*** group name below.
[image]

Comment: I can clearly see it work in your pictures, but for some reason my mind doesn't quite understand it; how does pinning the vertices of the pants objects keep the pant's pinned vertices group in relation to the (I think they're separate) objects of the microphone-shaped bone-looking objects? I just don't see where it's made distinct you want to pin to the leg/waist object, and not empty space >.<

Comment: See, when I do that, this is what happens:

https://i.gyazo.com/2d37473f934d48708537f348054a68ea.gif

Comment: Just parent the pants to the body (in Object Mode select the pants first, then select the body and press Ctrl+P-->Set Parent to-->Object) and it will follow it.

Comment: Aha! That... Woops. https://i.gyazo.com/3fae5dccd7a69a1083b32f62a635cff7.gif

It definitely is a step forward, but why are the pants slowly getting absorbed by his legs? : s The body does have collision on as well as the pants.

Comment: Would it help if I added my blend file? :s

Comment: The problem you've described is quite common. To avoid a cloth entering the mesh you have to play with its settings. Check out this answer:  http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43602/how-to-prevent-a-cloth-from-entering-another-mesh

Comment: Been playing with it, and its helping a little bit but not very much :/

Comment: Try to make the legs much thinner. As you can see in my .gif above it works quite fine then. Also I've noticed that the issue appears when you rapidly move the body. Try to move it slower. Sorry, but I have no other ideas how to help you right now :/. Though I'll try to update my answer, when I find a proper solution in future. Cheers :).

Comment: I suppose I could but I would prefer a solution that is more reliable :/ What do you normally do when you model pants on a character?

Comment: @elemein I just found out that you may increase the **simulation steps** to make it work well. Please check out this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30463/how-to-simulate-cloth-on-a-fast-moving-character